# How can I search for nearest users using longitude and latitude but also filter by sex and age in an efficient way in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, gis, geospatial

I am used to BTREE indexes, and I know how to apply multi column indexes to optimise normal queries.

I have a sample database like this:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `gis`;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `gis`
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE `gis`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    id           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname    VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
    sex          ENUM('male', 'female') NOT NULL,
    age          TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    position     POINT NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE user ADD INDEX sex__age (sex, age);
ALTER TABLE user ADD SPATIAL INDEX(position);

INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Alexander', 'male', 34, POINT(63.429909, 10.393035));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Dina', 'female', 21, POINT(63.426300, 10.392481));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Martin', 'male', 32, POINT(63.422304, 10.432027));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Tina', 'female', 19, POINT(63.430603, 10.373038));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Kristin', 'female', 20, POINT(63.434858, 10.411359));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Mette', 'female', 33, POINT(63.420422, 10.403811));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Andres', 'male', 34, POINT(63.419488, 10.395722));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Sandra', 'female', 25, POINT(63.432053, 10.408738));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Kine', 'female', 29, POINT(63.432302, 10.412643));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, sex, age, position) VALUES ('Henrik', 'male', 25, POINT(63.421055, 10.443288));
```

If I do a normal query and query by sex and age it uses the proper index and only looks for 2 rows in this query, which is what it should do and it shows me that the query and index is working properly.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id, firstname, sex, age FROM user WHERE sex = 'male' AND age BETWEEN 25 AND 32;
```

It uses key: `sex__age` index and does a range seek as expected because of age,
rows checked is 2 only, which is good.

But then I try to do a lookup by position, and check users that are within 3.5 km, but it checks all the rows and does not use the spatial index.

```
SET @distance = 3.5;
SET @my_place_lng = 63.431592;
SET @my_place_lat = 10.396210;

SELECT
    id,
    firstname,
    sex,
    age,
    ST_Distance_Sphere(Point(@my_place_lng, @my_place_lat), position) AS distance_from_me
FROM user
WHERE
    ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope(
        Point((@my_place_lng+(@distance/111)), (@my_place_lat+(@distance/111))),
        Point((@my_place_lng-(@distance/111)), (@my_place_lat-(@distance/111)))
    ), position)
ORDER BY distance_from_me ASC;
```

How can I do this and let MySQL use the spatial index?

And also I already know that I can't combine RTREE and BTREE indexes so spatial and normal indexes can't be combined. Any suggestion to how I can optimise something like this?

Comment: On how many rows are you testing that query? Sometimes MySQL decides not to use an index on small tables.

Comment: It is 10 entries only

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k1Xqp44wm8w4JVbqDShQnh/0) with 16K rows. The engine still don't want to use the index. `FORCE INDEX` improves the query time significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get any warning when creating spatial index? MySQL has weird behavior about SRID requirements as explained here

https://mysqlserverteam.com/geographic-indexes-in-innodb/

Try setting SRID.

Comment: I got no warnings